# Test case for Action ngrx 4

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, angular-test

i am new in ngrx, we have angular proj which is usig ngrx storing/state the data. and now i have to write a test case for the all action, reducer and other code. but i am stuck in writing test cases for the actions. looked in google but no help found.

```
export enum ProjAction {
   INSERT_RECORD = "[ProjAction] Insert a record."
}

export class ProjActionCreator(private store: Store<ProjState>) {
   insertRecord(data: any) {
        this.store.dispatch(<Action>{
           type: ProjAction.INSERT_RECORD,
           payload: data
        })
   }
```

}

i tried to make a spy object and dispatch but it won't help for me.
any help will appreciated.

Comment: https://ngrx.io/guide/store/testing => You can test components using mock or actual store implementation. 
https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/ngrx-store-testing-actions => Testing actions
https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/ngrx-store-testing-reducers => Testing reducers

Comment: @AliF50 thank you for sharing the link. i visited the link earlier also but in my case it won't work. i have written the test case for the rest of others component link ng comp, service, store and others. just stuck in writing test case for Action as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

For this you need simply to assert that `this.store.dispatch` has been called with desired arguments.

```js
it('test', () => {
  // preparation
  const store = TestBed.get(Store);
  spyOn(store, 'dispatch');

  // action
  component.insertRecord({test: '123'});

  // assertion
  expect(store.dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
    type: ProjAction.INSERT_RECORD,
    payload: {
      test: '123',
    },
  });
});
```